# PHP Сonvert string to nested array with keys

Tags: php, arrays, string, nested

I have a string - `$string = '_8;1092;4,_9;1083;4,_10;1084;4,_11;1085;4;'`.
I need convert it to array like this:

```
$args = array(
    8 => array(
        'product_id' => 1092,
        'quantity' => 4,
    ),
    9 => array(
        'product_id' => 1083,
        'quantity' => 4,
    ),
    10 => array(
        'product_id' => 1084,
        'quantity' => 4,
    ),
    11 => array(
        'product_id' => 1085,
        'quantity' => 4,
    )
);
```

Tried this method:

```
$prods = explode( ',' , $string );
foreach ( $prods as $prod ) {
    $prodsParam = explode( ';' , $prod );
}
```

but it's not quite what I need.
Also I do not understand how to convert the first value in a string '_9', '_10', etc. in an index of the nested array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '_8;1092;4,_9;1083;4,_10;1084;4,_11;1085;4';
$exploded = explode(',', $string);
$array = [];

foreach ($exploded as $item) {
    $values = explode(';', $item);
    $index = (int) str_replace('_', '', $values[0]);
  
    $array[$index] = [
        'product_id' => (int) $values[1],
        'quantity' => (int) $values[2],
    ];
}
```

try that.
You first explode on the comma as that is the seperator for each item. Then inside the foreach loop explode on the ";" delimiter to get each value. The rest is easy for setting the correct information `(int)` is used to convert the values to a integer value.

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1092
            [quantity] => 4
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1083
            [quantity] => 4
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1084
            [quantity] => 4
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1085
            [quantity] => 4
        )

)
```